# MVC Model with inherited nested class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, model-view-controller, interface

Looking to implement an MVC model a bit like this, but where a person class has a Telecoms class that can be a phoneline or a PhonelineAndBroadband class where I can access the ITelecom Price() method easily for a list of . Is this the best way of approaching this? What would go in the Person class?

```
class Person
{

}

abstract class Telecoms
{

}

interface ITelecoms
{
    void Price();
}

class Phoneline : Telecoms, ITelecoms
{
    public void Price() {...}    
}

class PhonelineAndBroadband : Telecoms, ITelecoms
{
    public void Price() {...}    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would recommand is using only the abstract class. Which will be your base class. It will contain an *abstract* method that contains the Price() method. Then, you can get rid of polymorphism, one of the fundamentals of Object Oriented programming in order to implement this method into the sub-classes.
So, eliminate the interface, because the Price() would be accessed in the Base abstract class rather than highering your design's complexity with adding the ITelecoms interface.

```
abstract class Telecoms
{
    public abstract void Price();
}
```

And then for your sub-classes

```
class Phoneline : Telecoms
{
    public override void Price() {...}    
}

class PhonelineAndBroadband : Telecoms
{
    public override void Price() {...}    
}
```

With a code like this, you will have a clean,compact, OO respecting design.

Answer (score 0):

Person class should have property of type `ITelecoms`.

```
public class Persons
{
    public ITelecoms Telecom {get;set;}
}

Person p1 = new Person {Telecom = new Phoneline()};
Person p2 = new Person {Telecom = new PhonelineAndBroadband()};

List<Person> persons = new List<Person>{p1, p2};

persons.ForEach(r=> r.Telecom.Price());
```